# WPF Dynamic value on a custom property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, user-controls

I Have a User Control which contains Expander and few other controls.

User control have a custom "XBackground" property which actually sets the background only for the Expander.

```
    public Brush XBackground
    {
        get
        {
            return expander.Background;
        }
        set
        {
            expander.Background = value;
        }
    }
```

When I use my user control, background can only be set statically, not dynamically. Debugger says that only DependencyProperty can be set via dynamic resource. And here I'm stuck. I tried to register dependency property on my XBackground property but I'm receiving an error saying "A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Here is my try of registering dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BcgProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("XBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(Expander));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use `typeof(Expander)`, but instead the type of your UserControl as the `ownerType` argument of the `Register` method. In addition you'll also have to call `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the property wrapper.

Besides that, you would also have to a register a `PropertyChangedCallback` with the property metadata, to get notified about property value changes:

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    public Brush XBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(XBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "XBackground",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(YourUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, XBackgroundPropertyChanged));

    private static void XBackgroundPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var userControl = (YourUserControl)obj;
        userControl.expander.Background = (Brush)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

---

An alternative to the `PropertyChangedCallback` would be to bind the Expander's `Background` property to the UserControl's `XBackground` property in XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
    <Expander Background="{Binding XBackground,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yes! I did not know how to access my control from inside of the `XBackgroundPropertyChanged`, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Minor mistake:

public static readonly DependencyProperty BcgProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("XBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(**YourCustomUserControl**));

Full version:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XBackgroundProperty 
            = DependencyProperty.Register("XBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(YourCustomUserControl));
public Brush XBackground
{
    get { return (Brush) GetValue( XBackgroundProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( XBackgroundProperty, value ); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Owner class in Register is not an Expander, but the name of the class in which your DependencyProperty is registered.
Try this:

```
    public Brush XBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(XBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for XBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("XBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(/typeof your UserControl goes here/), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: Well, the error is gone, but now my control is transparent, color is not applied.

Comment: Show your xaml, it looks like you do not set the Source for Binding correctly

Comment: Source should be fine, it works for all other pre-set properties. `XBackground="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=bcgResource}"`